# SQLite count in left join request

Tags: sqlite, count

My model is 1 wine can have many bottles. These bottles have a field output_type NULL or NOT NULL.

Actually, I can count the bottles like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(bottles.id)) AS total_bottles
FROM wines
LEFT JOIN bottles ON wines.id = bottles.wine_id AND bottles.status=1 AND bottles.output_type IS NULL
```

This works well.

But now I need more: I want to count the bottles stored (output_type NULL) AND count the bottles gone (output_type NOT NULL) in the same request.

So my LEFT JOIN is not enough because I can't count the bottles stored and the bottles gone in the main request.

I have seen something like this, including a "sub request" in the LEFT JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS bottle_stored FROM bottles WHERE bottles.status=1 AND bottles.output_type IS NULL) AS total_stored ON wines.id = bottles.wine_id
```

But this is not working. If this was working, I can duplicate the LEFT JOIN to count gone bottles.

EDIT:
More explanations here. This is my current request. I can count all bottles stored (output_type IS NULL) for each wine.

```
SELECT wines.id, wines.winery
COUNT(DISTINCT(bottles.id)) AS total_bottles
FROM wines   
LEFT JOIN bottles ON wines.id = bottles.wine_id AND bottles.status=1 AND bottles.output_type IS NULL 
WHERE wines.status = 1  
GROUP BY wines.id
```

EDIT 2 (DB schema added):

```
wines table
-----------
id (vc)
winery (vc)
name (vc)
status (int)
...

bottles table
-------------
id (vc)
wine_id (vc)
input_type (int)
input_date (datetime)
output_type (int)
output_date (datetime)
status (int)
...
```

I want:

- to list all wines
- to count bottles stored (output_type NULL) for each wine of the list
- to count bottle gone (output_type NOT NULL) for each wine of the list

in the same request.

My primary and foreign keys are varchar because it's UUID (global sync system).

Comment: Isn't there a missing GROUP BY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(bottles.id)) AS bottles_stored, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(bottles.id)) AS total_bottles
          FROM wines
          LEFT JOIN bottles ON wines.id = bottles.wine_id AND bottles.status = 1) - COUNT(DISTINCT(bottles.id)) AS bottles_gone
  FROM wines
  LEFT JOIN bottles ON wines.id = bottles.wine_id AND bottles.status = 1 AND bottles.output_type IS NULL
```

1. Select all bottles that are stored => bottles.output_type = NULL
2. Subquery for counting the total amount of bottles
3. Subtract bottles_stored from total_bottles => bottles that are gone

**UPDATE AFTER SECOND EDIT OF muqaddar:**

First, a query to list all wines (1):

```
SELECT w.id,
       w.name,
       w.winery
  FROM wines
```

Next, we count all bottles stored (2) and bottles gone (2) for a specific wine id = 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id) 
  FROM bottles AS b 
 WHERE b.output_type IS NULL AND 
       b.wine_id = 1
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id) 
  FROM bottles AS b 
 WHERE b.output_type IS NOT NULL AND 
       b.wine_id = 1
```

As a third step we combine of all three queries with query (2) and (3) as subqueries and we replace the static id = 1 by w.id from the outer query:

```
SELECT w.id,
       w.name,
       w.winery,
       (SELECT COUNT(b.id) 
          FROM bottles AS b 
         WHERE b.output_type IS NULL AND 
               b.wine_id = w.id) AS bottles_stored,
       (SELECT COUNT(b.id) 
          FROM bottles AS b 
         WHERE b.output_type IS NOT NULL AND 
               b.wine_id = w.id) AS bottles_gone
  FROM wines
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this seems to count all bottles gone for every wine and add them as the result. I don't have the gone bottles for each wine.

Comment: Then you have to give us more details about the problem and perhaps some code or the database design for your tables.

Comment: When I do the second SELECT to count bottles, it's counting all bottles for all wines, not the bottles each wine.

Comment: As I said please provide some more detailed explanation (e.g. structure of the database tables). Guessing is a waste of time!

Comment: Sorry Paul, I have added some details about the DB schema. Thanks.

Comment: Done. See if it is what you wanted. ;)

Comment: This is just perfect. I now get the right counts. Thanks a lot Paul.

Comment: No prob. For next time: Tend to us with as much information as possible about your problem. That makes it easier for us to find a (the correct) solution. ;)